# Base case for printing String using recursion when the String length is an odd number

Tags: java, recursion

my program uses recursion to print a String in the form of a triangle:

```
Sample input: "abcdefghij"
Sample output:
aj
abij
abchij
abcdghij
abcdefghij

Sample input: "abcdefghi"
Sample output:
    a
   abi
  abchi
 abcdghi
abcdefghi
```

Issue is this works only when String length is even. Please how do i adjust the base case to print the very middle character?
Here is my code:

```
public class DisplayTriangle
{
  public static void main(String[]parms)
  {
    print ("abcdefghij");
  }
  public static void print(String str)
  {

    int mid = str.length()/2;
    String first="";
    String last="";
    print(str,0,str.length()-1,first,last);
  }

  public static void print(String str, int start, int end,String first, String last)
  {
    if( start >= end ||  end <=start )
    {
      return;
    }
    first+=str.charAt(start);
    last =  str.charAt(end)+last;
    System.out.println( first+ last );
    print(str, (start+1), (end-1), first, last);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also show us the desired output?  How many characters do you intend to remove during each recursion?  Your code appears to be currently removing 2 characters at a time, but what would happen with an odd-length string?

Comment: i just added what the sample ought to look like @tim-biegeleisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it, without excessive string concatenation, and with correct indentation:

```
private static void print(String str) {
    if (! str.isEmpty())
        print(str, (str.length() - 1) / 2, 1, (str.length() - 1) | 1);
}
private static void print(String str, int indent, int leftLen, int rightIdx) {
    for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++)
        System.out.print(' ');
    System.out.println(str.substring(0, leftLen) + str.substring(rightIdx));
    if (leftLen < rightIdx)
        print(str, indent - 1, leftLen + 1, rightIdx - 1);
}
```

*Output*

```
    aj
   abij
  abchij
 abcdghij
abcdefghij
```

```
    a
   abi
  abchi
 abcdghi
abcdefghi
```

*Explanation*

The second `print` method should be pretty obvious: Print `indent` spaces, print `leftLen` character from `str`, and all character starting at `rightIdx`. If not done, recurse with one less indent, one more from left, and one character earlier from right.

Looking at the sample output, the value of `indent` should be `4` for both length `10` and length `9`, so `(str.length() - 1) / 2` will calculate that.

First call should always print `1` character from the left, so that's simple.

Now, the initial value of `rightIdx` should be `9` for the even length `10`, so the `j` will be printed, and should also be `9` for the odd length `9`, so nothing will be printed. So, for lengths `10`/`9` we subtract `1` to get `9`/`8`, then set lowest bit (`| 1`) to make it `9`/`9`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below modified version of your print function

```
public static void print(String str, int start, int end,String first, String last)
  {
  if( start > end ||  end <start )
  {
    return;
  }
if(start==end){
    first+=str.charAt(start);
    last =  str.charAt(end+1)+last;
    System.out.println( first+ last );
    return ;
}
first+=str.charAt(start);
last =  str.charAt(end)+last;
System.out.println( first+ last );
print(str, (start+1), (end-1), first, last);
}
```

Comment: for input "abcdefghi", an odd length string, first line prints: "ai" and last line prints "abcdeffghi"

Comment: sorry i forgot to remove one line .can you please comment `last=str.charAt(end+1)+last;` which is inside of `if(start==end)` block

Comment: @i_use_the_internet if this solves your problem can you please accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do with 2 methods

```
1. for even , e.g, 

    if(string.length()%2==0)

    {
    //Method for Even
    }

2. for odd , e.g, 

    else

    {
    //Method for odd
    }
```

Comment: Please try to explain your technique instead of copy pasting.